# Asset catalog ios 6 launch image and icon

Tags: assets, catalog, ios6.1, launchimage

xcode give me error with the asset catalog, but in the asset catalog there are all the images that xcode want.. where i'm wrong? Thanks!
this is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the error? Aren't catalogues only supported from iOS 7.0 ?

Comment: OK, iOS6 does support asset catalogues but is seems the launch images must still be named correctly (Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png) etc.